# Получение статичных файлов asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

сейчас в проекте для возвращения файлов использую много методов HTTPGet в одном контроллере. Отдельный метод для отдельного файла. Можно ли как то объединить в один?

Пример

```
...
[HttpGet]
public IResult Index()
{
   return ReadTextFile("Content/index.html");
}

[HttpGet("indexStyles.css")]
public IResult IndexStyles()
{
   return ReadTextFile("Content/indexStyles.css");
}

[HttpGet("indexScript.js")]
public IResult IndexScript()
{
   return ReadTextFile("Content/indexScript.js");
}
...
```

Преобразовать в

```
[HttpGet()]
public IResult GetFiles()
{
   //возврат любого запрашиваемого файла
}
```

Comment: `GetFile(string filename) { return ReadTextFile(filename); }`

Comment: Добавить путь как аргумент метода нельзя?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov когда я так делаю параметр filename остается пустым и функция обрабатывает только запрос к корневой странице `https://localhost:7177/`. Файлы стилей, скрипты и т.д. возвращают 404

@bubadev думаю оно мне и нужно, только я не знаю как это сделать